# Matlab Boxplots

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'd like to create a quasi boxplot graph as shown on pages 15/16 of the attached report.

comisef.eu/files/wps031.pdf

Ideally I only want to show the median, the maximum and minimum values as in the report.

I would also like to have similar spacing to that shown in the report.

Currently I have two matrices with the all the necessary values stored in them but have no idea how to do this in matlab.

The boxplot function gives too much data (outliers etc) which makes the resulting graph look confused especially when I try to plot 200 on one page as in the original report.

Is there another function that can so the same thing as in the report in matlab?

Baz

OK here is some test data each row represents 10 sets of estimations of a data set, and each column represents the test number for a given observation.

As boxplot works on the columns of the input matrix you will need to transpose the matrix.

Is it possible to turn outliers and the inter-quartile ranges off? Ideally I just want to see the maximum, minimum and median values?

You can repeat the data below to get up to 200. Or I can send more data if necessary.

```
0.00160329732202511 0.000859407819412016    0.000859407819411159      0.0659939338995606    0.000859407819416322    0.000859407819416519    2.56395024851142e-15    2.05410662537078e-14    0.000859407819416209
1.67023155116586e-06    8.88178419700125e-16    1.67023155115637e-06    0.000730536218639616    1.67023155105582e-06    3.28746017489609e-15    4.41416632660789e-15    1.67023155094400e-06    1.67023155097567e-06
1.42410590843629e-06    1.42410590840224e-06    1.76149166727218e-15    5.97790925044131e-15    1.42410590843863e-06    2.87802701599909e-15    9.31529385335274e-16    9.17306727455842e-16    0.000820358763518906
8.26849110292527e-16    3.23505095414772e-15    4.38139485761850e-07    4.38139485938112e-07    4.38139485981887e-07    0.000884647755317917    3.72611754134110e-15    4.38139485974329e-07    4.38139485923219e-07
0.000160661751819407    0.000870787937135265    0.000870787937136209    1.16934122581182e-15    9.02860049358913e-16    1.18053134896556e-15    1.40433338743068e-15    0.000870787937135929    1.13510916297112e-15
1.16934122581182e-15    3.80292342262841e-05    3.80292342263200e-05    0.00284904319356532 1.74649997619656e-15    3.80292342264024e-05    0.00284904319356537 1.01267920724547e-15    0.00284904319356540
   0.100091800399985    0.100091773169254   0.100091803903140   0.000770464183529358    0.100091812455930   3.49996706323281e-05    3.49996706323553e-05    1.05090687851466e-15    0.100091846333800
0.00100555294602561 0.00100555294601056 0.105365907420183   0.000121078082591672    9.02860049358913e-16    0.000121078082591805    4.49679158258033e-15    7.77684615168284e-16    0.000121078082591693
0.122539456858702   0.000363547764643498    0.000363547764643509    0.122516928568610   0.0101487499394213  0.122408366511784   0.000363547764643519    1.13510916297112e-15    0.122521393586646
0.000460749357561036    0.000460749357560646    3.27600489447913e-13    1.18053134896556e-15    0.000460749357561239    1.54689304063675e-15    0.000460749357560827    0.000460749357561205    1.16934122581182e-15
```

Comment: Actually I am starting to think that boxplot is not the suited to this problem. I think this is closer to what I want: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35294-matlab-plot-gallery-errorbar-plot/content/html/Errorbar_Plot.html

Comment: Analogously to the example I can calculate the median, man and min and plot the median value with the max and min representing the error bars (seems non symmetric errorbars are possible). Do you know how to control the spacing for errorbars?

Comment: ah no it seems that won't work to have the asymmetric errorbars you have to plot the data against another variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using boxplot, I suggest just drawing lines from the min to the max and making a mark at the median. Boxplot draws boxes from the 25 to 75 percentile, which doesn't sound like what you want. Something like this:

```
% fake data
nPoints = 100;
data = 10*rand(10, nPoints);

% find statistics
minData = min(data, [], 1);
maxData = max(data, [], 1);
medData = median(data);

% x coordinates of each line. Change this to change the spacing.
x = 1:nPoints;

figure
hold on

%plot lines
line([x; x], [minData; maxData])
% plot cross at median
plot(x, medData, '+')
```

[image: line plot for min, max and median]

EDIT: To have horizontal lines and a second axis you can do something like this:

```
figure
h1 = subplot(1,2,1);
h2 = subplot(1,2,2);

% left subplot
axes(h1)
hold on
%plot lines
line([minData; maxData], [x; x])

% plot cross at median
plot(medData, x, '+')

% link the axes so they will have the same limits
linkaxes([h1,h2],'y')
% turn off ticks on y axis.
set(h2, 'YTick', [])
```

[image: horizontal min, max, median line plot]

Comment: Ah yes that's more like it, sorry for suggesting boxplot which was wrong. I would like to turn this graph 90 degrees effectively transposing the values and then draw it side by side with another graph so that (ideally) they share the same y-axis (which in the example above would be 1-100 after it's been rotated. But each has its own x-axis. Please see the pdf in my original question. Can it be done?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a question of playing with the settings. You can try:

```
boxplot(X, 'plotstyle', 'compact', 'colors', 'k', 'medianstyle', 'line', 'outliersize', 0);

Explanation:
'plotstyle', 'compact': makes the boxes filled and the lines undashed
'colors', 'k': color is black
'medianstyle', 'line': the median is marked by a line
'outliersize', 0: if outlier size is zero, you don't see them

Other you can try:
'orientation', 'vertical': this flips the orientation, depends on your data
'whisker', 10 (or higher): this sets the maximum whisker length as a function of the interquartile limits (if you crank it up, it will eventually default to max and min values), I wasn't sure if this is what you wanted. Right now, it goes to the 25th and 75th percentile values.
```

The spacing is going to depend on how much data you have. If you edit with some data, I can try it out for you.